# KendoGrid with in a new custom kendo ui widget

Tags: kendo-ui, jquery-widgets

Please guide me how to make a custom kendo ui widget, like if you could refer to some tutorial or anything. Secondly the main question is that I want to use kendo grid to consume webapi and i want to use it in a widget in which and pass the datasource to this widget.

Bascially I want to make a widget which will consume the webapi using a particular url, and which will return a data source that I can add to this kendogrid widget.

Comment: is that possible ? or my question is unclear?

Answer (score 2):

Googling a little I just found:

[Creating Custom Kendo UI Plugins](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-04-03/creating_custom_kendo_ui_plugins.aspx)

[Creating a DataSource Aware Kendo UI Widget](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-04-10/creating_a_datasource_aware_kendo_ui_widget.aspx)

[Inheriting From Custom Widgets](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-10-16/inheriting_from_custom_widgets.aspx)

[Creating A Kendo UI MVVM Widget](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-04-24/creating_a_kendo_ui_mvvm_widget.aspx)

I think that any and all this blogs should help you (I've written several widget and I found here all I needed).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Emiliano's links, the Kendo Music Store demo app also contains a custom Widget bound to a DataSource that you can look at as an example:

Live demo site: http://www.kendouimusicstore.com/

Source code: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-music-store

Custom Widget source: [MvcMusicStore/Scripts/App/kendo-cart-menu-widget.js](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-music-store/blob/master/MvcMusicStore/Scripts/App/kendo-cart-menu-widget.js)

Documentation for this custom widget: http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/ASP.NET/Kendo%20Music%20Store/Music%20Store%20Web/kendo-music-store-web-cart-menu-widget

---

If you are going to use WebAPI, you will probably want to [read this (The Facts On Using Kendo UI With ASP.NET WebAPI)](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-11-29/the_facts_on_using_kendo_ui_with_asp_net_webapi.aspx) first.
"Use WebApi" is a very broad statement, and narrowing down your approach would be the first step.